# Random button Android project

Tags: java, android, random

I want to make an app that when you click a button it will go to a random place on the screen. I want it to be an ImageButton the when onClick well go to a random place on the screen. I've attempted before. But to no success. Here is some of the code I've already attempted with. --->

```
package com.example.e99900004533.candycollector;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public EditText collectedTextEdit;
    public ImageButton candyEdit;
    public int collected = 0;
    public int screenWidth = 300;
    public int screenHeight = 300;
    Random random = new Random();
    public boolean running = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        collectedTextEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.collectedText);
        candyEdit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.candy);
        collectedTextEdit.setText("Collected: " + collected);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;

        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        candyEdit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                collected += 1;
                collectedTextEdit.setText("Collected: " + collected);

                int candyX = random.nextInt(screenWidth - 50);
                int candyY = random.nextInt(screenHeight - 50);
                System.out.println(candyX + " : " + candyY);

                MarginLayoutParams marginParams = new MarginLayoutParams(candyEdit.getLayoutParams());
                marginParams.setMargins(candyX, candyY, 0, 0);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(marginParams);
                candyEdit.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                //if (candyX > screenWidth) {
                    //screenWidth -= 50;
                    //layoutParams.setMargins(candyX, candyY, candyX, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    //candyEdit.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                //}
                //if (candyY > screenHeight) {
                    //screenHeight -= 50;
                    //layoutParams.setMargins(candyX, candyY, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    //candyEdit.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                //}

                //while (running == true) {
                    //candyY -= 1;
                    //layoutParams.setMargins(candyX, candyY, candyX, candyY);
                    //candyEdit.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                //}
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you are using Android Studio as it gives you a beautiful way of accessing all the benefits of the Android API.

Anyway, before I post the code, you set the onClickListener within your java code and while that is fine, it can clutter up your code. A much more aesthetically pleasing solution is to use XML and a button's android:onClick. You will see this in the code.

Java:

```
package testinc.com.randombutton;

import android.graphics.Point;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    // Encapsulating the data just to be safe...
    private int collected = 0;
    private int screenWidth = 300;
    private int screenHeight = 300;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;

        TextView collectedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collectedTV);
        collectedView.setText("Collected: " + collected);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void toRandomPosition(View view) {
        // Based on our collection candy collection:
        collected += 1;
        TextView collectedView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.collectedTV);
        collectedView.setText("Collected: " + collected);

        // Based on position of our candy:
        Random random = new Random();
        // Understand nextInt(N) will go from 0 -> N-1, also are you trying to control where it can go?
        float candyX = (float) random.nextInt(screenWidth - 50);
        float candyY = (float) random.nextInt(screenHeight - 50);
// I didn't write it, but you need to check these float values if they   exceed the screen width and the screen length. */
        // Sout to check coordinates
        System.out.println(candyX + " : " + candyY);

        // To change margins:
        ImageButton imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.changePlace);
        imgButton.setX(candyX);
        imgButton.setY(candyY);
    }
}
```

Android:
Note: I used a linear layout because I dislike the relative. You can change it without repercussions I suppose.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/collectedTV"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/changePlace"
                 android:onClick="toRandomPosition"
                 android:contentDescription="It's a button, ha za"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Key parts:**

`android:onClick="toRandomPosition"` hooks up with the method, `public void toRandomPosition(View view)`

`setX` and `setY` require floating point numbers to set the position. Unfortunately, it seems that the random class does not have nextFloat(float n) in its class. I recommend just casting the int as a float for now.

Seeing that I am doing this now, here is a possible (I have not checked it) solution to the coordinates going beyond the bounds of the screen:

```
while ( candyX >= screenWidth || candyY >= screenHeight) {
  candyX = (float) random.nextInt(screenWidth - 50); 
  candyY = (float) random.nextInt(screenHeight - 50);
}
```

I checked if the position was equal because a button at the corner of the screen is a pain to find and may be skewed off the display.

Comment: || only work for boolean's. But thank you very much :D

Comment: The comparison statements ( >=, <=, >, <, ==) will give boolean values, and thus essentially work for any number comparison.